# I can't use Paypal with REST request

Tags: rest-api, paypal

I've set up a test store with Magento 2.2. I use one test paypal account for the store and one for the customer. I've set up Paypal in the configuration panel and managed to buy a product using the web store.

Now, I want to do it, using a webhook with REST request. I can add stuff to my cart and use offline payment method, no problem. Here's my code for the checkout

```
const header_valid = {'content-type': 'application/json',
                          'Authorization': "Bearer " + token };
    const url_valid = site+"carts/mine/payment-information";
    const postbody_valid = JSON.stringify({
        "paymentMethod" : {
            "method" : payment // payment ="paypal_express" in this case
        },
        "billing_address" : {
            "email" : "",
            "region" : adress.region.region,
            "region_id" : adress.region.region_id,
            "country_id" : adress.country_id,
            "street" : adress.street,
            "postcode" : adress.postcode,
            "city" : adress.city,
            "telephone" : adress.telephone,
            "firstname" : adress.firstname,
            "lastname" : adress.lastname
        },
        "shipping_address": {
            "email" : "",
            "region" : adress.region.region,
            "region_id" : adress.region.region_id,
            "country_id" : adress.country_id,
            "street" : adress.street,
            "postcode" : adress.postcode,
            "city" : adress.city,
            "telephone" : adress.telephone,
            "firstname" : adress.firstname,
            "lastname" : adress.lastname
        }
    });
    request.post({
        headers : header_valid,
        url : url_valid,
        body : postbody_valid
    },function(error_valid,response_valid,body_valid){
        if(error_valid)
            console.log(intent + "\n Erreur : " + error_valid);
        else{
            console.log(intent + "\n"+ JSON.stringify(body_valid));
            if(JSON.parse(body_valid).message)
                send_message(res,"Problème",id,Parametre);
            else send_message(res,"La commande a été validée",id,Parametre);
        }
    });
```

However, when i use this to access the store and try to checkout my cart , i get the message "Problème", and this is body_valid.message:

```
"{\"message\":\"PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token).\"}"
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Did you get PayPal API Token? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_api_flow/

Answer (score 2):

We also had the same issue when we tried the below payload it worked

Endpoint: http://localhost:8888/Magento/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

`{
"paymentMethod": {
"method": "paypal_express",
"additional_data": {
"paypal_express_checkout_token" : "EC-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"paypal_express_checkout_redirect_required" : false,
"paypal_express_checkout_payer_id" : "XXXXXXXXXX"
}
}
}`

In order to get the payment token we used the paypal set express checkout api directly

Here is more details

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/?mark=Do%20Express%20Checkout%20Call#

When the customer approves the payment we will get the payer id in the returned url.

Hope this helps!

Sorry for putting this as answer I don't have the reputation to comment